# How to make Gummi use TeX Live 2018 instead of 2017?

Tags: ubuntu, gummi, texlive-2018

Gummi is a fantastic live preview TeX editor. The problem I am facing with Gummi is that even if I install TeX Live 2018 separately using install-tl from the install-tl-unx.tar.gz file, I still have to install old texlive dependencies  that come with gummi using apt install and Gummi only uses those (2017 version).

Is there a way to make it point to TeX Live 2018 ?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 bionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after I posted the question I found a simple work around.

First I installed TeX Live 2018 with `install-tl` from the [install-tl-unx.tar.gz](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) file using this [Guide](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#installation). Follow the post-install checks mentioned in the guide.

Install Gummi with `sudo apt install gummi`

Manually remove TeX Live 2017 dependencies installed with gummi using

1. `apt remove texlive-base`
2. `apt remove texlive-binaries`

If your PATH variable properly points to TeX Live 2018, Gummi should detect and use it automatically.

**Update 1:**  The proper solution as pointed out by @[daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif)  is to use the `--no-install-recommends` flag. This won't install the recommended dependencies.

Comment: You could probably just install gummi without texlive by adding the `--no-install-recommends ` flag, or by building and installing the equivs package (Google "Debian vanilla texlive" for a description

Comment: @daleif Thanks. "--no-install-recommends" seems like a proper solution.

Comment: @daleif you may add the answer. I'll mark it correct.

Comment: No need just add it to your own answer for others to find